# Spring Data JPA - changes are not visible outside the environment/application

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am using Spring data jpa to store and read entities across diffferent applications. Below are the steps that are executed:

1. Application 1 creates an entity via jpa repository and stores it into db with `saveAndFlush()` method
2. It then sends an event to queue saying, entity is created
3. This event is then read by another application (let's say Application 2) which then tries to read the entity and processes it

Following is the example method used to store the object:

```
@Transactional
public Entity createEntity(final Entity entity) {
    return entityRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

As per the documentation, `@Transactional` annotation should make sure the object gets persisted once method execution is finished. However, when Application 2 receives an event and tries to look up the entity (by id), it is not found. I am using Maria DB and Spring Data JPA 1.9.4.

Do we need to do anything else to force hard commit after saveAndFlush call?

Comment: Are you sure the applications are looking in the same place?

Comment: Yes, Application 2 is able to find the entity if same event is sent after like 10 seconds..

Comment: it is weird. Are you saying that waiting 10 seconds before to advice the 2nd application make the data available for reading? Are you sure your transaction is flushed before noticing the 2nd application? if it is the case, this data incoherence may come from your infrastructure

Comment: Yes, I am using `@Transactional` annotation as well as `saveAndFlush()` method. So, as per the documentation, it should flush the transaction.

Comment: Do you have both a `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?  Without the `COMMIT`, the changes have not been made persistent, and no one else can see them.  (No, I don't know the what language Spring has used to obfuscate these necessary commands.)